# Differential equation how to find out bounded or not bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

For which value of the parameter $k$ will all solutions of remain bounded as $t \rightarrow  \infty$?
$$u''(t)+k~u(t)=2 \sin(10t)?$$

Comment: Are you able to find $u(t)$ and then do analysis on the result?

Comment: yes it is U(t)= c1cos(k(1/2)t)-c2sin(k(1/2)t)+Kp

Comment: That does not look correct

Comment: I mean root over k in both cases and by kp i mean particular solution

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question after receiving an answer.

Comment: I did not get my answer

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Solve for the complementary solution.
- Solve for the particular solution.
- Form $y(t)$ and then analyze the limit against values of $k$.

The solution you should arrive at is:

$$y(t) = c_1 \cos(\sqrt{k} ~t) + c_2 \sin(\sqrt{k}~ t) + \dfrac{2}{k-100} \sin(10t)$$

Now, can you analyze what happens as $t \rightarrow \infty$ for different values of $k$ and figure where it remains bounded?

Comment: not really ????

Comment: Is it k is getter than o and not equal to 100. but i am not really what the questiom means by bounded?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function

Comment: @user112211: What do the trig functions do as $t \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Nice work, @Amzoti! +1 Did you mean "Now" or "Not" at the start of your last sentence?

Comment: I simply assumed it was a "typo", literally...a mistake in typing, not in grammar!

Comment: You are correct - and it is fixed! Thx!